# Set f:viewParam property to null when there is no parameter in URL

Tags: jsf-2, viewparams

Let's assume we got simple page that accepts one parameter:

```
<f:viewParam name="name" value="#{bean.name}"/>
```

When user goes to `http://localhost/myapp/?name=Joe`, then `#{bean.name}` is set to `Joe`.
Then if user goes to `http://localhost/myapp/` or `http://localhost/myapp/?something=Else`, then `#{bean.name}` is still set to `Joe`, but I want it to be `null`. How this can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the right managed bean scope for the data it holds. You've apparently put it in the session scope. Put the bean holding the parameter in the request or view scope instead of session scope and when using view scope, make sure that you navigate by a normal link or by a post-redirect-get when performing an action.

#### See also:

- [How to choose the right bean scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031885/how-to-choose-the-right-bean-scope/7031941#7031941)

Comment: Yes, it's session scoped and should be, since it holds user preferences. I just want to set bean attribute only when param contains this attribute, otherwise NULL. My idea was to use preRenderView listener and manually check this param and set null.